# SSD SMART test status failing - how to interpret?

Tags: 18.04, ssd, smart

I recently installed the latest Ubuntu on my MacBook Air following a SSD failure. After running smartmontools I identified the problem as attribute 173 is failing.

```
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE   
173 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0036   100   100   100    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 11703984196361
```

How do I interpret this? Does this warning have a strong correlation with actual SSD failure?

Comment: WHEN_FAILED=FAILING_NOW.  ID#173 is a SMART error, I would interpret that as an actual failure. You should read [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-test-solid-state-drive-health-gnome-disks) and cross check with Gnome Disks. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same FAILED notification for my Samsung SM951 (AHCI) 128GB, reported in Linux as `SAMSUNG MZHPV128HDGM-00000 (BXW2500Q)`.

But in my case, I think it's a firmware bug of the drive because the `total-bytes-written` property is reported as 1.1TB while the drive has a specified Total Bytes Written (TBW) of 75TB! Which probably is on the very save side, because similar (MLC NAND) drives all reached a multitude of that (600TB) in [a real endurance test](https://techreport.com/review/26058/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-data-retention-after-600tb). And apart from the `wear_level_count` warning no other prefail or old age errors or warnings are reported, while the `reallocated-sector-count`, which according to that test is a good pre-fail indicator, is still 0.

So my advise would be to examine those values for your drive/system and base your conclusions on that.

I prefer the low-level utility `skdump` which is supplied with `libatasmart`, the same library that is used by [Gnome Disks](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-disk-utility).

Use the following command, replacing `/dev/sdc` with the path to your block device:

`sudo skdump /dev/sdc`

Regards.